# What’s a university’s policy for late paper (lab papers) in case of technical issues?

Tags: undergraduate, grades, coursework, policy

I faced an issue where a large amount of my lab papers got deleted near the completion of the semester. Some of those reports where combined and data collected in multiple weeks. Paper lengths were more than 10 pages.

After looking through my university’s policy it seems that the instructor (non responsive) has most of the decision making.
Therefore, I wanted to know at the undergraduate level what is a department head’s approach to this is?

If the issue arises days before finals week is additional consideration taken?

Backups did save some of my work but restored files were not relevant to the course.

Comment: Is this technical issues under your control, or under the departments?

Comment: That sounds like a "the dog ate my homework" kind of excuse. It's your job to make sure data doesn't get lost, unless you explicitly know that someone else is in charge.

Answer (score 3):

For your university's escalation policy you'd have to check... well, your university's policy.

If I understand your question right, you did not keep appropriate backups, and near the end of the semester lost a substantial amount of your work. If this is the case, this is all on you, and you are at the mercy of the instructor feeling sorry for you. As I tell my students, you didn't have computer problems, you had a failure-to-backup problem.

As for appealing to the department chair, that is always an option. But beware that department chairs are usually tougher than instructors when it comes to lame excuses, and you might get your head bitten off.